# React router does not work correctly when used with react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react application in which I have 3 component, AdminShopRoutes, AdminShop and Products.

The AdminShopRoutes Component:

```
const AdminShopRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header>
                <AdminShop exact path='/admin/shop' component={Dashboard} />
                <AdminShop exact path='/admin/shop/customers' component={Customers} />
                <AdminShop exact path='/admin/shop/products' component={Products} />
            </Header>
    </Router>)
 }
```

The AdminShop Component

```
const AdminShop = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
        true
            ? <Component {...props} />
            : null
    )} />

)
}
```

And finally the Product Component

```
const Products = (props) => {
     useEffect(() => props.getProducts(), [])
     const { products, loading } = props
     return ( ... )
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getProducts })(Products)
```

The links present in the other components beside these work i.e the url is changed but the page is blank as soon as the url changes for every route. If I then refresh the page, it renders fine but only on REFRESH. Also if I omit the route rendering the Products component all other routes work fine. Is there some other method of using hooks when working with react router because it is something to with Products component. Any help would be  appreciated.

This is the warning I get when i render the product page

[image: This is what I get when i render the product page]

Comment: Try wrap the routes in `Switch` and remove exact from all exept the first

Comment: It still does not work. It has something related to do with the connect keyword of redux that is what i figured out by now. Because if I toggle between home page and customer page it works fine, as soon as i go to products page and then again to customers or home it renders ablank page

Comment: Do you see any errors? You get the fetched data?

Comment: Yes a warning instead, i have modified the question and added the error snap

Comment: And yes i do get the fetched data but along with this warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrow functions without `{}` will return the value of their one statement.

Arrow function with `{}` require an explicit `return` statement to return a value.

So the result of `props.getProducts()` is being returned from your effect.

However, `useEffect()` restricts the return value to only be a cleanup function for that effect. A non function return value is considered to be an error by React.

To fix this, just add `{}` to your arrow function so that it does not return a value:

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.getProducts()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

do this

```
useEffect(() => {
  props.getProducts()
}, [])
```

so that `props.getProducts()` doesn't get returned

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows this has nothing to do with routing, but your useEffect is returning something when it shouldn't.

The error is pretty verbose and clear.